# react router not working with webpack dora?

Tags: reactjs

am trying to set up my routers for my app, and have the basic home route entry point working (seemingly). It seems when I try to start adding sub routes, it is breaking. I have a pretty straight forward set up right now.  However not of my routes are working can someone please help ? thanks

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Home from './src/Home';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Help from './src/Home/Help';

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
const About = () => <h1>About Us</h1>

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

//
    webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = function(webpackConfig) {
  webpackConfig.babel.plugins.push('transform-runtime');
  webpackConfig.babel.plugins.push(['import', {
    libraryName: 'antd',
    style: 'css',
  }]);

  return webpackConfig;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're only experiencing this issue while running on `localhost` then this is the problem:

You need to add `historyApiFallback: true` to your Webpack Configuration.

So update your `webpack.config.js` to the following:

```
module.exports = function(webpackConfig) {
  webpackConfig.babel.plugins.push('transform-runtime');
  webpackConfig.babel.plugins.push(['import', {
    libraryName: 'antd',
    style: 'css',
  }]);
  webpackConfig.historyApiFallback = true;

  return webpackConfig;
};
```

This should do the trick!